# Why is Buffer assignment triggering an unsafe assignment error?

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

I have a TypeScript project that is leveraging ESLint.  I have a class that utilizes a [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer) as a class attribute.  I want to be able to set the buffer as part of construction.

**example.ts**

```js
export class Example {
    public myBuffer: Buffer

    public constructor(myBuffer: Buffer) {
        this.myBuffer = myBuffer
    }
}
```

This block yields the following linter error:

```
5:3   error  Unsafe assignment of an `any` value          @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
```

What is causing TypeScript to interpret this typed parameter as `any`?  Do I need to somehow import the `Buffer` type?

As shown in this picture, my IDE does detect that "myBuffer" is of type `Buffer`:

[image: a screenshot of my IDE]

**My Dev Dependencies**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/register": "^7.8.6",
    "@jest/console": "^25.1.0",
    "@tsconfig/node16": "^1.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.23.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.23.0",
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sort-exports": "^0.6.0",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "nock": "^12.0.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  }
```

Comment: When you hover over `myBuffer` on the right hand of the assignment line, what type does your editor say it is?

Comment: Is this a node-specific question?  Could you provide a [mre] or a link to an IDE project that displays this issue?

Comment: @AlexWayne it claims it's a Buffer; I'll update the question with a screenshot.

Comment: @jcalz great point, yes, this is a Node project and I'm intending to reference `Buffer` in Node.

The code snippet is all there is to my project, aside from the eslint config (I'll make that more clear in the question).

Comment: @jcalz your question helped solve my issue -- I had not added `@types/node` to my project, which did the trick.  If you would like to provide the answer I'll give you the internet points (otherwise I can self-answer).

Comment: Feel free to self-answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me!

The issue is that I had not added `@types/node` as a project dependency.  Since `Buffer` exists within Node (rather than TypeScript) the type was not defined when linting without that addition.

Running `yarn add --dev @types/node` (or `npm install @types/node --save-dev`) does the trick.